# algorithm2e: How to customize caption of the "procedure" environment?

Tags: numbering, algorithm2e, naming

The *procedure* environment requires the caption to be in a very restricted form: "Name()". However, I would like to add more details like: "my awesome procedure $A = (para1, para2)$". How would I do that?

Actually, this caption is possible in the *algorithm* environment, alternatively, how to change the label, e.g. Algorithm 1, of the environment into "procedure".

Comment: Regarding your latter comment: Do you want to change "Algorithm 1" into "Procedure 1"?

Comment: @Werner: I also want to remove the counter, it should be only "procedure".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to change `Algorithm` to `Procedure`, you can do the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{Procedure}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }

  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The *name* of the algorithm is stored in `\algorithmcfname`, which you can redefine to suit your needs. You can also use `\SetAlgorithmName{#1}{#2}{#3}` where

- `#1` denotes the name associated with the List of Algorithms
- `#2` denotes the name associated with the `algorithm` environment
- `#3` denotes the name associated with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)'s `\autoref` name

---

Assuming that you want to remove the numbering of the **Procedure**, you also want it removed from the List of Algorithms, and therefore not have any counter associated with it. The following redefinition of `\@caption` within a new `algoproc` environment does that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{algoproc}[1][]
  {\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{Procedure}%
   \begin{algorithm}[#1]
   \long\def\@caption##1[##2]##3{%
     \par
     \begingroup\@parboxrestore
     \if@minipage\@setminipage\fi
     \normalsize \@makecaption{\AlCapSty{\AlCapFnt\algorithmcfname}}{\ignorespaces ##3}%
     \par\endgroup
   }}
  {\end{algorithm}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algoproc}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }

  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algoproc}

\end{document}
```